# Is it acceptable to drastically change a question after you've got an answer, stating that the answer was "unsatisfying"?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26550962/2) just popped up with a bounty. The OP states:

> This was an old question with an old and unsatisfying answer. Updated and added a bounty

Checking the revision history, it seems like the question changed pretty dramatically from the first version to the second version. So much so that the previous answer doesn't make a lot of sense — it refers to "distinguishing the errors from the process from the timeout", but that doesn't occur in the question anymore.

To complicate matters, the OP also added a bounty on the updated question.

What is the suggested direction for questions like this?

*Note:* I edited the question some for general style and clarity before I noticed the large change in content. You may want to ignore my changes for making any determinations.

Comment: Happened with me many time, I end up either writing a note on the top of my answer and I refuse to change or I delete my answer.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In general I'd say it's not acceptable.

Drastically changing the question invalidates the existing answers, which is something that we'd like to avoid.

If you've realised that you've asked the wrong question it would be far better to ask a new, better question. By all means link back to the original question if you think it will help, but you'd probably be better off not doing that.

However, you'd have to look at the actual revision and what's been done. Did they change the title as well as the body? Is it actually a better restatement of the problem?

In this case, the title of the question is the same but the body is totally different and a new question.

IN cases like this flag the question for moderator attention (rather than exposing it on meta) and we'll look into it. Bounties *can* be refunded if there is good cause.

Comment: Is there anything to be done about the bounty? Could it be transferred to a new question?

Comment: Missed that. We could refund the bounty if we're feeling generous, but under normal circumstances it's spent.

Comment: @ChrisF In this case, the question (and this goes for many old rust questions) refers to an api, a version of rust, that doesn't exist any more. You can, technically, hunt down an old version of rust, but practically speaking, no one uses old rust. All rust code now should be post 1.0. I appreciate drastically editing is considered to be (to broadly use the term) vandalizing, but how is it beneficial to leave these old answers up? They *actively* mislead people looking for answers. Should the title be changed? The tag removed? The question edited? What's the right way of handling it?

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? Why not have the op just ask a new question and reference the old question... of course it could potentially be marked as a duplicate, but adding verbiage about "using version 2.0" or the like could be done.

Comment: That is exactly what ChrisF's answer from last year proposes.

Comment: oh well, it's significantly shorter, anyway, so it's the Reader's digest condensed version!