# Is it OK for an OP to cut and paste an answer to modify his code in the question without acknowledgment

Tags: discussion, attribution

I am referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60608448/split-values-using-powershell)

The questioner had a number of problems he was trying to overcome with his code, the main issue he was having was how to use a regular expression to extract some values and then put them in the relevant columns of a csv.  I answered his question at which point he notified me his requirements had changed and he needed the values in a database. I was unable to help him with this.  However I was surprised to discover that he had literally cut and pasted my answer code into his as part of the modified question. Is this OK? I flagged it but am not sure if that was the right thing to do.

Aggravating factors include - the number of times the requirements kept changing (this was the 2nd question he asked as the first one was closed as duplicate). In the first he asked a simple question so in the comments I suggested he needed to escape a $. At which point he keeps coming back to me asking for more ideas, then moved me to chat, then asks me for my social media account

Comment: Worth reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire

Comment: Which revision did you answer: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60608448/revisions

Comment: I answered the first one which basically got him over the major hurdle and allowed him to move to the next bit

Comment: I would normally rollback to revision 2 but I can't really judge if that invalidates the other answer.

Comment: consensus is that it is not OK to change the question after it got answers: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302443/is-it-acceptable-to-drastically-change-a-question-after-youve-got-an-answer-st

Comment: Yes it would actually invalidate the other answer tbh. I am happy to let it go - but just wanted to get a steer as to whether it is acceptable. Even if he had just written a comment acknowledging the help I would have been satisfied

Comment: also relevant on MSE:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: Thanks that is spot on!! Chameleon questions lol - it has it's own terminology :-)

Comment: Turns out I have answered on a similar case before: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted

Comment: Brilliant! You don't want to come across as sour grapes but you do put time and effort into it.  Thankyou

Comment: Thanks guys - I now know how to handle the situation because of the links that you have given me. In this particular case I will retract my flag as I have all the info I needed.  Appreciated

Comment: If you can indicate what the original question was in the revisions, a field expert may revert it back to that one (as @rene suggested; I'm not a field expert in this either so won't make the call). Of course it may invalidate answers made after that – but that's, unfortunately for the answers, not the point.

Comment: @usr2564301 Rolling it back would invalidate the accepted answer - I am happy to leave it as it is - As it has never happened to me before in such a blatant way I was pretty sure it wouldn't be OK with the community but wanted to check