# New questions have been overzealously marked as duplicates for YEARS

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Ok guys, it's a meme at this point. New person asks question, and within 10 minutes it gets marked as a duplicate by some high-reputation user. And y'know what? A lot of times, perhaps the overwhelming majority of the time, they're right to mark it as a duplicate, and it's a good thing to remove the question because it's just a poorly-asked variant of a question that was asked 10 years ago.

On the other hand, this is like 99% of where complaints of "toxicity" and elitism come from when people complain about SO off-site, and for the last 5-10 years, a lot of people just don't bother anymore and ask the question on Reddit and get a better reception. And I figure this question will probably get the same reception (but believe me, I put a lot of effort into looking for a similar question on meta, only to come back empty-handed), get closed as a duplicate, and disappear into the abyss, only for this long-standing problem to continue unsolved. This might just be another case of "Man yelling at cloud".

I think this attitude of reaching quickly for the "Mark as Duplicate" ban-hammer has created a web of blind spots of questions that *could have been* answered but are erroneously regarded as duplicates. In a [recent exchange with another user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47840659/5079779), I suggested asking a question for something that, indeed, is ***nowhere to be found*** across all of Stack Overflow, or even Google searches for that matter. And y'know what, they don't even want to bother asking the question because it will more than likely get marked as a duplicate. They even link to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956205/solvability-of-a-version-of-lights-out-game) that was erroneously marked as a duplicate ages ago that would *probably* be the question it would be considered a duplicate of.

This problem is ***that bad***, and it has been for nearly 10 years. Mods and high-rep users are *so overzealous* about marking duplicates that nobody is bothering to ask new questions about old topics. Stack Overflow has effectively become read-only for everything that has been around for more than a few years.

And it's funny too, because most other sites on the network don't have this problem.

#### So what's the solution here?

In my most charitable analysis of the problem I can fathom, perhaps there's just too much crap coming down the pipe to actually pay attention to necessary details to properly distinguish low-effort real duplicates from actual blind spots. Perhaps there is a shortage of qualified and properly incentivized volunteers tackling this problem. Reputation is damn near impossible to get unless you were around in the early days of the site, so basically no one can get the rep to even downvote, let alone view the review queues- and then there's still little incentive to engage with the review queues. And with one controversy after another driving out good moderators and active users that make this site what it is, perhaps it shouldn't be surprising that there aren't enough good and motivated reviewers (which effectively turns otherwise good reviewers into a bad ones by starving them of the time they need to do the job well).

I think this problem is deeply systemic, and in essence, I don't have any ideas that wouldn't require a total overhaul of nearly everything about the SE network, its systems, and probably its business model. I hope someone else has actionable ideas.

I'm hoping my rant can bring about discussion for change that people have been hungry for over the last decade. But alas, I suspect this will probably get downvoted into oblivion as it ruffles some feathers and ultimately accomplishes nothing. I have no reason to expect that my rant will bring about any positive change just because I complained to the right people about something that everyone already knows is a problem. I'm a nobody with less than 1000 reputation on SO, but I think I speak for a lot of people in my rant above.

So make of it what you will. I'm hitting the submit button now.

Comment: Sure, it's easy to close a question as a duplicate but it's just as easy to reopen it. Perhaps not enough people are actually reopening incorrectly closed questions.

Comment: FWIW mods do reach out to some users who incorrectly close as a duplicate. But that's rather rare.

Comment: If only we had a sort of... staging... area where questions could go to be checked out/improved prior to them being posted, with enough people interested in using it for it to work efficiently

Comment: Why is a question getting marked as a duplicate intrinsically bad to you? If someone asks a question, and we can find a duplicate (usually because they couldn't do their own research), then we can give them a wide variety of answers much more quickly. If anything, there are too many people answering low quality questions that are blatant duplicates.

Comment: "Why is a question getting marked as a duplicate intrinsically bad to you?" It isn't "intrinsically" bad, but when mods and reviewers are too excited about marking duplicates that you mark non-duplicates as duplicates, it leaves gaping blindspots of problems and questions that are *similar*, but have different answers. These questions are already not duplicates and do not need to be edited to be made non-duplicates.

Comment: Imagine if we marked all problems that are NP-complete as duplicates of 3SAT. I mean, sure, they technically are duplicates in a mathematical sense, but that "duplicateness" is completely meaningless without explaining the proof of NP-completeness for that problem, which itself is an interesting answer that will be different for every distinctly different NP-Complete problem. On top of that, you also can consider optimizations of that mapping or the solution itself, which constitutes additional questions. A lot of SO feels like this sort of thing to a lot of people.

Comment: `And y'know what? A lot of times, perhaps the overwhelming majority of the time, they're right to mark it as a duplicate`.  Ok great, so there's no problem then.

Comment: I'm confused, why do you have a heading *"So what's the solution here?"* when you don't offer a solution? Your post doesn't feel like it's inviting discussion either, it is just a rant; that's not a good way to invite discussion, as it's not clear what you actually want to discuss. What are you looking for a solution to? How to do better research before asking? How to make use of the duplicates that questions are closed as? Something else?

Comment: As I discussed, there's also a chilling effect that happens when most questions are marked as duplicates (especially from the perspective of a new user) that *actively discourages* users from asking questions out of fear of downvotes and being marked as a duplicate. But yeah, this is tough to balance against the very real need to filter out the avalanche of bad questions that legitimately are duplicates.

Comment: If I ask a well asked question, and it gets closed as a duplicate which answers the question that's not "chilling", it's good; I have the answer to my question. If I ask a bad question and get the answer (due to being closed as a duplicate), that's still good for me as I got the answer; it's just bad on me that I made a poor attempt at asking (or researching).

Comment: It's absolutely chilling if people are discouraged from asking questions in the first place. (even if they're good)

Comment: So it's bad that we provide users with links to existing content? Are you suggesting that bad question should get answers because directing them to good content is "bad"..? I fail to see how pointing users to a solution is "discouraging" them to ask questions. They asked a question, they got an answer. How is that discouraging someone to ask again? Such people are here for *answers*, not to provide good content (as often duplicates can be easily found).

Comment: Speaking for myself only: I don't care if people complain, I only care if their complaints are valid. I also don't care *one iota* if people use other sites or find them more accommodating.

Comment: If these questions are not duplicates, why are the authors not modifying them, to make it clear their reason(s) the answers to the already existing question does not actually answer the question they asked? You say reviewers are too excited to close questions, I say users are too excited to ask their questions and are actually asking questions that has already been answered.

Comment: You also say "most questions" are marked as a duplicate, but on the first 5 pages, I see a very low number of questions closed as a duplicate. I see no evidence people are discouraged from asking questions based on the number of new questions that have been asked in the last hour.  "Reputation is damn near impossible to get" - **This is absolutely false.**

Comment: @Thom A: Not at all. Sometimes those links are useful. "Related" doesn't necessarily imply "duplicate", however. Pointing to some other similar problem and its answers isn't always going to help you solve that problem. Maybe it should be harder to mark things as duplicate. Maybe this is a cultural issue. Maybe duplicates aren't inherently a problem (low-quality questions are) and could lend themselves to very interesting insights that aren't present in a related question. Or maybe it's a matter of incentives; that there is no compelling reason to to a good job other than intrinsic motivation.

Comment: @Beefster - Questions are not closed if they are "related", if users are closing questions as duplicates with an answer, that does not answer the actual question then that question is being improperly closed.  You say this has been a problem for years but don't provide any actual metrics to validate that statement

Comment: If the question is related, then it wouldn't be closed as a duplicate. We close as *duplicates* not "as related", @Beefster .

Comment: I think this flies in the face of the average user's experience on the site. Dozens of Youtubers have demonstrated how downright hostile the site seems to new users and it never changes. There are endless memes about this that entering the site as a new user results in your question getting closed as a duplicate of an only-vaguely-related question. If what the memes say is wrong, then prove them wrong. If it really is a skill issue, then a skilled and high-rep user should be able to replicate their success on a new account by writing several well-researched questions.

Comment: At this point in the history of Stack Overflow, for most *mature* technologies, I'd expect *almost* every question to have already been answered. See new questions closed as duplicates should really not be surprising at all. To me, that means Stack Overflow is working.

Comment: There are always more questions to ask. Just because the most frequently asked questions have already been asked over 10 years ago (where the bulk of any high-rep user's reputation comes from), doesn't mean everything else that's slightly related to those FAQs is a duplicate. And yeah, I don't exactly want it turning into Quora, but still I think we're missing out on a lot of good questions that people aren't asking because of the prevailing perception of the site experience.

Comment: I suppose then the question is how to educate new users how to ask good questions...

Comment: If only the [Staging Ground](https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground) went Live...

Comment: "Dozens of Youtubers have demonstrated how downright hostile the site seems to new users, and it never changes." - I can almost guarantee you that their issues with the community are due to their unwillingness to address the issues with their questions, and mistakenly believe, we should simply answer their questions the way they asked them regardless of the quality of their questions.

Comment: @SecurityHound I once again reiterate my challenge (maybe I should make it into another meta question) to some madlad high-rep user to replicate some measure of success on a new account. If it's truly a skill issue, *show the world how it's done* and put the memes to rest. If they run into nothing but roadblocks and failure, maybe it's time to reflect on the site experience and figure out what needs to change.

Comment: I think it would probably also help to direct users toward other platforms that are more likely to provide the type of experience they are looking for. Reddit and programming Discords are probably a better avenue for 95% of the questions that people would otherwise ask here because they *aren't within the scope* of SO's vision and goals.

Comment: Re *"Reputation is damn near impossible to get unless you were around in the early days of the site"*: An (unethical) way is to ***literally*** ask thousands of (low-quality) questions and *ignore* downvotes, etc. This will give tens of thousands of reputation points. The system rewards quantity over quality.

Comment: "They even link to another question that was erroneously marked as a duplicate ages ago that would probably be the question it would be considered a duplicate of." The duplicate used in that case is absolutely suitable - except that it is **itself** a duplicate, and **all** of them are **clearly** closable as "needs more focus" anyway (including the one at the end of the duplicate chain).

Comment: "The duplicate used in that case is absolutely suitable - except that it is itself a duplicate" - then the problem is the quality of the question, not whether or not it is a duplicate.

Comment: @Beefster - If the question is low quality it should be downvoted and eventually pruned for being low quality after a period of time. It should also be closed until such time it’s no longer low quality and can be answered (or closed as an appropriate duplicate target) or pruned for being abandoned. It most certainly is possible to earn reputation by asking questions in 2023

Comment: "Reputation is damn near impossible to get unless you were around in the early days of the site" - Assuming I figured out the right SQL, [accounts created just within the last week have accumulated almost 24000 reputation](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1794626).

Comment: _'"Mark as Duplicate" ban-hammer'_... AFAIK there are no penalties (eg _bans_) for having your question marked as a duplicate

Comment: @Beefster - I don’t need to participate in this challenge, I already earned reputation from both questions I asked and those I answered, and SO wasn’t new when I did so. I am not willing to participate in a challenge based on a concept that I don’t believe to be accurate. The hostility comes from those new users in my experience, in my experience they serially downvoted my contributions, because I dared provided feedback suggesting their question was not clear or was out of scope. I don’t need to expose myself to that hostility, again, I avoid it today for a very good reason

Comment: "I once again reiterate my challenge (maybe I should make it into another meta question) to some madlad high-rep user to replicate some measure of success on a new account." I did that in 2018: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2018/09/19/farewell-daisy-shipton/ - "Daisy" didn't **ask** any questions, but *did* manage to gain a reputation of about 12,000 in under 6 months from answers, proving that it's perfectly possible to still get rep from more recent questions.

Comment: "Mods and high-rep users are so overzealous about marking duplicates" and "A lot of times, perhaps the overwhelming majority of the time, they're right to mark it as a duplicate". If users are getting it right the *overwhelming majority* of the time, how can you also say that they're *so overzealous* about marking duplicates?

Comment: If posts are overwhelmingly being closed as duplicates (even correctly) people are receiving less personal help on average than they were when less posts were being closed as duplicates.

Comment: [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63898/user63898?tab=questions). More than 1000 questions. The writing is still low quality after nearly 15 years. I have always wondered if it was due to general ***sloppiness***, ***deliberate*** (made hard/difficult to read on purpose), or (lack of) ***ability***.

Comment: Perhaps writing good questions is just really hard and there isn't a lot of patience for it because of the enormous volume of exceptionally bad questions.

Answer (score 24):

> New person asks question, and within 10 minutes it gets marked as a duplicate by some high-reputation user.

This gets you an answer faster. A lot of the time the user's problem could've been resolved by doing proper research, that's sort of why we have "canonical" questions, because people keep asking the same question over and over again. Other times the user lacks the requisite knowledge to do proper research, either way, we're still answering their question. It's important to remember that duplicates are based more on the answer than on the question, this has been a [longstanding precedent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358763/how-similar-does-a-question-need-to-be-to-another-to-be-marked-as-a-duplicate).

> they're right to mark it as a duplicate, and it's a good thing to remove the question because it's just a poorly-asked variant of a question that was asked 10 years ago.

A duplicate question is not inherently worth deleting. It may be a novel perspective that still has the same underlying answer. It can create a [signpost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417601/change-the-stigma-regarding-signposts) that helps other users find the answer faster.

> On the other hand, this is like 99% of where complaints of "toxicity" and elitism come from when people complain about SO off-site, and for the last 5-10 years, a lot of people just don't bother anymore and ask the question on Reddit and get a better reception.

I've heard stuff like this a lot. We still have a lot of users (both those who ask and answer questions, and people who find an answer here). Just because we're more interested in creating a library of high quality Q&A, and Reddit is willing to repeatedly answer the same zero research question, doesn't mean that we're doomed to fail. Even if no more questions are ever asked, we still have a lot of information available here. I'd bet that a lot of the answers on Reddit source their information from SO.

> I think this attitude of reaching quickly for the "Mark as Duplicate" ban-hammer has created a web of blindspots of questions that could have been answered but are erroneously regarded as duplicates.

Marking as duplicate is not a "ban-hammer". As far as we're aware, a question being marked as a duplicate has no effect on a question ban. Marking as a duplicate gets people answers. Why wouldn't you want that to happen quickly in the overwhelming majority of cases?

Of the cases where the duplicate was erroneous, there usually was an underlying problem with how the question was asked that prevented one from fully understanding the true underlying question. That's why you have the ability to edit your question to clarify how it is not a duplicate, and why we have the ability to re-open questions. In these cases, getting closed was still good, as it resulted in the question getting clarified such that it could be answered correctly. In fact, if the opposite had occurred, and the question had been answered (albeit a duplicate answer), you might be more upset to find out that your attempts to change your question are [rejected because they would invalidate an existing answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302443/is-it-acceptable-to-drastically-change-a-question-after-youve-got-an-answer-st).

---

As with many things I see people complain about, this is only perceived as bad by people who fundamentally misunderstand our goals. Our goal isn't to help **you**, it's to help **everyone** who has the same question in the future.